# how do i implement visual themes like ask.com?

Tags: php, asp.net, themes

how do i implement themes like ask.com to my websites? Should i be using Ajax, according to one of my friend it is done using JQuery? Also it will be a great help if someone can redirect me to a tutorial (asp.net and/or php). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/) has many good tutorials for starters.

As for your query regarding [Ask.com](http://ask.com/), you can build something similar using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You may just need to change the style when *peel* is clicked. For example:

```
$('.peel').click(
    function() {
        $('.container').css( 'background-image', 'http://url/to/image/' );
    }
);
```

Comment: Though, for someone asking this question, he may not really know where to look at that site.

Answer (score 0):

there are ways lol :)

you could use jquery. or you could use js
however you still need the power of css on this.
you would first have a default theme default.css
then a optional theme optional.css

then you would have to change the source of your < script > tag

other wise if you really understand javascript and html

check this page out... http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ then check the gallery button. see how they do it there.

but it sounds like you are not experienced and i think you are trying to run before you can walk. Learn the basics of html and javascript on w3schools.com then you should be good to go they have amazing tutorials there